# $createUserWithEmailAndPassword when using AngularFire is creating user but isn't returning promise

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I'm currently migrating an existing project over to Firebase 3/AngularFire 2 from a previous Firebase.com setup. It's my first time working with each.

My question is: I'm using the `$createUserWithEmailAndPassword` example from the AngularFire docs and am wanting to add an updateProfile after the promise is returned, but I can't get anything to happen after the initial `$createUserWithEmailAndPassword` line. "Auth" is my factory returning `$firebaseAuth()`.

```js
Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password)
.then(function(firebaseUser) {
  console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
});
```

I am confirming via the Firebase/Google console that the Auth user is being added, but I'm not getting any errors in my console - just no promise returned. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Could you maybe also show your `Auth` factory?

Comment: there could be two reasons 1 Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword doesn't return promise 2 Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword doesn't resolve the promise in it's body..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a known bug which is already fixed in the upstream: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/790

Maybe you have to update your library to `2.0.1`?